# get_headers на хостинге показывает ложь

Tags: php, header

Когда скрипт выполняется на OPEN SERVER на моем компьютере ответ такой `"HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden"` и это правильный ответ.
Когда выполняется на виртуальном сервере на хостинге SPRINTHOST.ru ответ такой `"HTTP/1.1 200 OK"` это ложь!
В чем дело, почему хостинг заставляет скрипт выполняться по другому.

```
 $headers = @get_headers('https://user11183.clients-cdnnow.ru/hls/TV1000_HD/master.m3u8'); 
    echo $headers[0];
```

Comment: Подскажите, с чего Вы решили что ответ "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" это ложь?

Comment: если вставить ссылку в адресную строку то будет ошибка, + это ссылка не работает в plaer.js

Comment: @ДмитрийBulyha Ссылка рабочая и ответ корректный.

Comment: @Denis640Kb ссылка не рабочая 403 ошибка

Comment: Вы ошибаетесь. `Array ( [0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK [1] => Server: nginx [2] => Date: Fri, 03 Apr 2020 17:58:37 GMT [3] => Content-Type: application/vnd.apple.mpegurl [4] => Connection: close [5] => Last-Modified: Fri, 03 Apr 2020 17:58:35 GMT [6] => ETag: "5e87794b-1ff" [7] => X-Coder: mb-1 [8] => Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * [9] => Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, private [10] => X-Geo-Allowed-Country: yes [11] => X-Geo-Country: Russia [12] => X-Geo-Code: RU [13] => X-Geo-City: Moscow [14] => X-Edge-Cache: MISS [15] => X-Edge-Ip: 172.19.25.55 )`

Comment: array(11) { [0]=> string(22) "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden" [1]=> string(13) "Server: nginx" [2]=> string(35) "Date: Fri, 03 Apr 2020 18:11:38 GMT" [3]=> string(23) "Content-Type: text/html" [4]=> string(19) "Content-Length: 146" [5]=> string(17) "Connection: close" [6]=> string(25) "X-Geo-Allowed-Country: no" [7]=> string(22) "X-Geo-Country: Belarus" [8]=> string(14) "X-Geo-Code: BY" [9]=> string(21) "X-Geo-City: Dokshytsy" [10]=> string(23) "X-Edge-Ip: 172.19.25.48" }

Comment: я так понимаю это зависит от региона, с которого идет запрос

Comment: Вы видимо не на тот сайт делаете запрос, что указали. Адреса ip разные явно.

Answer (score 0):

ответ с локального сервера

```
array(11) { [0]=> string(22) "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden" [1]=> string(13) "Server: nginx" [2]=> string(35) "Date: Fri, 03 Apr 2020 18:32:31 GMT" [3]=> string(23) "Content-Type: text/html" [4]=> string(19) "Content-Length: 146" [5]=> string(17) "Connection: close" [6]=> string(25) "X-Geo-Allowed-Country: no" [7]=> string(22) "X-Geo-Country: Belarus" [8]=> string(14) "X-Geo-Code: BY" [9]=> string(21) "X-Geo-City: Dokshytsy" [10]=> string(23) "X-Edge-Ip: 172.19.25.48" }
```

ответ с хостинга

```
array(15) { [0]=> string(15) "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" [1]=> string(13) "Server: nginx" [2]=> string(35) "Date: Fri, 03 Apr 2020 18:32:20 GMT" [3]=> string(43) "Content-Type: application/vnd.apple.mpegurl" [4]=> string(17) "Connection: close" [5]=> string(44) "Last-Modified: Fri, 03 Apr 2020 18:32:20 GMT" [6]=> string(20) "ETag: "5e878134-1ff"" [7]=> string(13) "X-Coder: mb-1" [8]=> string(30) "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" [9]=> string(42) "Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, private" [10]=> string(26) "X-Geo-Allowed-Country: yes" [11]=> string(21) "X-Geo-Country: Russia" [12]=> string(14) "X-Geo-Code: RU" [13]=> string(18) "X-Edge-Cache: MISS" [14]=> string(23) "X-Edge-Ip: 172.19.25.12" }
```

в одном ответе `X-Geo-Allowed-Country: yes` а в другом `X-Geo-Allowed-Country: no`
это я так понимаю перенаправление зависящие от региона, от сюда и ошибка.

Answer (score 0):

403 Forbidden - доступ к файлу запрещён.

HTTP/1.1 200 OK - файл найден, доступ открыт.

Смотри права доступа